# PHP tell if a timestamp lies anywhere in the previousDay

Tags: php

Currently I am doing this to take the difference in days for two timestamps

```
function getDifferenceInDaysTillNow($timestamp) {
    try {
      $streakLastAwardedAtDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp);
      $streakLastAwardedAtDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

      $nowDateTime = new DateTime();
      $nowDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

      $diff = $streakLastAwardedAtDateTime->diff($nowDateTime);
      return $diff->format('%a');
    }catch(Exception $e) {
      throw new Exception($e);
    }
  }
```

[PHP Fiddle for the above approach](https://onlinephp.io/c/e4835)

This gives a difference of `1` (1day) if the timestamps have **24hours** difference.

But I just want to know if a timestamp lies in the previous day.
For example it can just be a difference of `2hours` or `6hours` doesn't matter.

I want to return a Boolean (true or false) telling if the provided timestamp lies in the previousDay or not.

Any help is appriciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can `->format()` both `DateTime`s with `Ymd` format and see if they are the same day.

Comment: Or you could take `nowDateTime` at 00:00 today, and then see if the compare timestamp is smaller than that (which means previous day), but not past 86400, ie. in yesterday's 24 hours range.

Comment: @MarkusAO Could you please provide a code example, 
"but not past 86400", could you please provide a snippet

Comment: Still unclear. Always show a minimum reproducible example with an online sandbox link. If the diff is in hours, what do you wish to return?

Comment: @nice_dev
I want to  tell if the provided timestamp lies in the previous day.

The above is the approach I tried, but it doesn't work because the difference is in days (24hours).
I am asking for a different approach, I just stated what I have tried already

Comment: @nice_dev I want to return a Boolean telling if the provided timestamp lies in previous day.

Comment: @SaiDarshan Ok, can you share an online PHP fiddle for this?

Comment: for the above given approach? ok sure, just a minute @nice_dev

Comment: @nice_dev added the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can simply check if the `y` or `m` property is greater than 0. If yes, return false. If the `d` difference is greater than 1, then also we need to return false since the difference is more than 1 day.

Additional check is to make sure the timestamp isn't the same day as today.

```
<?php
function getDifferenceInDaysTillNow($timestamp) {
    try {
      $streakLastAwardedAtDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp);
      $streakLastAwardedAtDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
  
      $nowDateTime = new DateTime();
      $nowDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
  
      // check difference between lastStreakAward and now
      $diff = $streakLastAwardedAtDateTime->diff($nowDateTime);
      if($diff->y > 0 || $diff-> m > 0 || $diff->d > 1) return false;
      return date("Y-m-d", $timestamp) != date("Y-m-d");
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e);
    }
}

$timestamp = 1670211229; // Monday, 5 December 2022 09:03:49 GMT+05:30
var_dump(getDifferenceInDaysTillNow($timestamp));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yr2wdujk)

Comment: use $nowDateTime = new DateTime('now',new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
A setTimeZone afterwards is wrong here. setTimeZone after the createFromFormat('U', $timestamp) is correct.

Comment: @jspit Might as well be. I didn't check that. I just focussed on OP's objective.

Comment: sorry, mistake on my part. For 'now' it doesn't matter. Only if an absolute date expression is used.

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime object is created from the timestamp, then converted to the correct time zone with setTimeZone and the time is set to 00:00. Then it can be compared directly with 'yesterday'.

```
$timestamp = 1670211229;  //5 December 2022 09:03:49

$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date_create('@'.$timestamp)
  ->setTimeZone($timeZone)
  ->setTime(0,0,0,0)
;
$isTimeStampFromYesterday = ($date == date_create('yesterday',$timeZone));
```

Comment: yes short and sweet

Comment: but date_create returns a object each time so if you compare it I am getting false